# Parameterized startswith query in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using the python bindings for sqlite3 and I'm attempting to do a query something like this

table1

```
col1 | col2 
------------
aaaaa|1
aaabb|2
bbbbb|3
```

test.py

```
def get_rows(db, ugc):
    # I want a startswith query.  but want to protect against potential sql injection
    # with the user-generated-content
    return db.execute(
        # Does not work :)
        "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE ? + '%'",
        [ugc],
    ).fetchall()
```

Is there a way to do this safely?

Expected behaviour:

```
>>> get_rows('aa')
[('aaaaa', 1), ('aaabb', 2)]
```

Comment: insteadd of adding percentage to query add it to ugc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL, `+` is used to add numbers.
Your SQL ends up as `... WHERE col1 LIKE 0`.

To concatenate strings, use `||`:

```
db.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE ? || '%'",
    [ugc],
)
```